# Cloud functions not firing, browser window also freezes when trying to view logs

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

My cloud functions are still using node 8, can't update to node 10 just yet

I am expecting my cloud function to fire once there is an update on the user doc

```
exports.updateUser = functions.firestore.document('users/{userId}').onUpdate((change, context) => {
  const after = change.after.data()
  if (after.status === 'VERIFIED') {
    console.log('EMAIL IS VERIFIED')
  }
  if (after.isVerified) {
    console.info(JSON.stringify(after))
    admin
      .auth()
      .getUser(after.uid)
      .then(() => {
        console.log('Email is verified')
        const metadataRef = admin.database().ref('metadata/' + userRecord.uid)
        return metadataRef.set({ refreshTime: new Date().getTime() })
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
      })
  }
  return
})
```

I had this working in the past, but not sure why it's not working now.

Right now the function is not even being called, and when I click 'view logs' in the firebase dashboard my whole browser window freezes - i'm not sure if this is related to my functions still using node 8

I can also confirm that the email is verified after clicking the link sent to my email using

```
firebase
      .auth()
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(inputs.email, inputs.password)
      .then(res => {
        const userUid = res.user.uid
        const db = firebase.firestore()
        // setUser(userUid)
        db.collection('/users')
          .doc(userUid)
          .set({
            emailAddress: inputs.email,
            uid: userUid,
          })
        res.user.sendEmailVerification()
      })
      .catch(err => {
        setErrors(prev => [...prev, err.message])
      })
  }
```

As well as logging in, accessing the `user` and `emailVerfied` is set to true

Answer (score 0):

Your Cloud Function code is going to generate some "erratic behaviour", which typically results in what you experienced ("I had this working in the past, but not sure why it's not working now").

You need to terminate a Cloud Function when all the asynchronous work is completed, see the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions). In the case of a background triggered Cloud Function you need to return the chain of promises returned by the asynchronous method calls.

In your case, not only you don't return the promise returned by `getUser()` but you have a `return` at the end that may indicate to the Cloud Function platform that it can clean up your function before the asynchronous work is completed.

The following should do the trick (untested):

```
exports.updateUser = functions.firestore.document('users/{userId}').onUpdate((change, context) => {
    const after = change.after.data()
    if (after.status === 'VERIFIED') {
        console.log('EMAIL IS VERIFIED')
    }
    if (after.isVerified) {
        console.info(JSON.stringify(after))
        return admin
            .auth()
            .getUser(after.uid)
            .then(() => {
                console.log('Email is verified')
                const metadataRef = admin.database().ref('metadata/' + userRecord.uid)
                return metadataRef.set({ refreshTime: new Date().getTime() })
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
                return null;
            })
    } else {
        return null;
    }
    
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the indepth answer, I didn't know about terminating cloud functions when it came to async work. Though, even with your updated code it still does not seem to be working

Comment: " it still does not seem to be working" do you see any error in the Cloud Functions log?

Comment: Theres no errors, I've even added a console.log at the start of the function to see if it fires - Which doesn't show.  I'm quite lost